# How to get last segment of the URL without GET variables in PHP?

Tags: php, string, url, uri

Now I have it like so:

```
<?
  $url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $requred_string= substr(strrchr($url, "/"), 1);
?>
```

and it returns the last segment, but it also returns all the `?p=y&g=x` gibberish that I don't need. How can I slice off the `$_GET` variables?

Comment: Use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: try to `print_r(parse_url($url));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strtok` to exclude the query strings:

```
$url = strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?');
$requred_string = substr(strrchr($url, '/'), 1);
echo $requred_string;
```

Or as mentioned in the comments, `parse_url` will work also:

```
$requred_string = substr(strrchr(parse_url($url)['path'], '/'), 1); // PHP 5.4 or greater with dereference
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a more elegant way `basename(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH))`